# liferay-portlet.xml: compilation error using show-portlet-access-denied, but suggested by autocomplete

Tags: java, xml, liferay, portlet

Adding the line below into liferay-portlet.xml I got  a compilation error, but I suppose that's spelled good because it is suggested by automplete.

```
<show-portlet-access-denied>false</show-portlet-access-denied>
```

After some check I see that Eclipse is marking "red" the related xml line.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I discover that element inside  tag are not order indepenedet. In fat moving  after  tag solved for me.

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>xxx</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <show-portlet-access-denied>false</show-portlet-access-denied>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>xx-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

Of course similar issue could be related whit all other tag not produce by Eclipse portlet creation wizard.